# Cannot enroll keys due to Shim IEFI Key Management not showing up after reboot

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, virtualbox, secure-boot, moklistrt

I am trying to sign an **nVidia kernel** and a **virtualbox module** using **mokutil**.

My problem is that the **Shim IEFI Key Management** is not showing up after reboot so that I can *enroll* the key.

Using `mokutil --list-new`, I can see that my key is scheduled to be enrolled. Also, the **Secure Boot** feature is *enabled*, alongside the mokutil validation. However, after rebooting, I expect the **Shim IEFI Key Management** to load, but I boot to Ubuntu, and the keys remain *not enrolled* (executing `mokutil --list-enrolled` gives: Failed to read MokListRT: No such file or directory)

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the nvidia driver I am trying to sign is 384.59, and my virtualbox version is 5.1.26.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can proceed, but they might not all work equally well, depending on your hardware and needs:

- Some EFIs provide an option to launch arbitrary programs. You can use this feature to launch MokManager (`MokManager.efi` or `mmx64.efi` in the same directory that holds `shimx64.efi` and `grubx64.efi`). This is likely to be the most direct approach, but this EFI feature is relatively rare, and even if it's present, there's no standardization on where it's located in the EFI's menu system, so you'll have to go looking for it.
- Prepare a USB flash drive with a FAT filesystem, create an `EFI/BOOT` directory on that drive, and copy some files from the `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` directory to the `EFI/BOOT` directory on the USB flash drive: Copy `shimx64.efi` and rename it to `bootx64.efi` in its new location and copy `MokManager.efi` or `mmx64.efi` without renaming it. (Your Ubuntu probably has `mmx64.efi`, but I don't recall when it was renamed.) You can then boot to the USB flash drive, which should launch MokManager.
- You can use an EFI shell program to do the job. Some EFIs have such a program built-in, but this is just as rare as the ability to launch arbitrary programs. If yours doesn't have such a feature, you can download one from the Internet -- see this [Arch Linux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Obtaining_UEFI_Shell) for some pointers. Put the program on a FAT USB flash drive, named `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. You should then be able to boot the USB flash drive into the shell and use it to run MokManager. Note, however, that you'll need to temporarily disable Secure Boot to run the EFI shell. You'll also need to learn enough of the EFI shell to navigate to the MokManager binary and run it. (This shell is similar to a DOS or Windows command prompt. The Arch wiki provides some tips on how to use it.)
- You can boot using my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB flash drive or CD-R. This should give you an icon to launch MokManager, or at least an EFI shell. As with launching an EFI shell directly, you'll need to temporarily disable Secure Boot for this option to work.
- You can install rEFInd to your hard disk by using the PPA or Debian package. When you reboot, MokManager should launch, enabling you to enroll rEFInd's keys and your own keys. This is a drastic method, since it will leave rEFInd in control of your boot process. Thus, unless you're sure you want to switch to rEFInd as your main boot manager, this is not a good option. I mention it only for completeness.

I'd try the options in more-or-less this order, although you can use your own judgment and skip something if you don't like the way it sounds or know it won't work.

Comment: Thank you a lot! What I had to do was: adding the `mmx64.efi` and `shimx64.efi` to the set of **trusted EFIs** so that they are allowed to be executed, via BIOS, and giving them the highest boot order. Consequently, after a reboot, the SHIM IEFI launched and I was able to enroll the keys. Appreciated.

Comment: I experienced precisely the same issue, but the solution for me was twofold. Firstly, executing `grub-install --uefi-secure-boot` allowed me to see the MOK Enrollment interface during boot (not sure why GRUB was lacking EUFI support to begin with). Despite adding my MOK and rebooting, the boot process would yield a black screen (and I mean pitch-black, even though the monitor was on). Then I thought back to some of Rod Smith's other posts on this subject, and it occurred to me that this might be a video issue, and to disable CSM (Compatibility Support Module) in BIOS. BINGO! Thank you both!!!